# jQuery adding closing input tags automatically and breaking my layout

Tags: jquery

I am appending the following html onto an element:

```
var radio = '<input type="radio" name="ShippingMethod" value="'+datum.Charge+'">';

$('#ShippingOptions').html(radio);
```

The problem is that it is automatically adding `</input>`, and breaking the layout of the page. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @Satpal no, that didn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: Just curious, How that will break the layout? Can you post html?

Comment: please provide html code of #ShippingOptions

Comment: I assume you want to add html step by step thats why you don't want to close the tag immediatly? If so, you first have to build the whole html string and then append it altogether.

Comment: Radio buttons don't work that way... In fact every `<input>` type property work the same. Use a `<textbox>` or `<button>` for inputs that aren't closed immediately.

Comment: What is the resulting html? `console.log($('#ShippingOptions').html())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that the closing `</input>` tag is breaking the layout. Building Strings and just placing them in the DOM is sometimes tricky. Why don't you use this syntax instead:

```
var radio = $('<input>',{type:"radio",name:"ShippingMethod",value:datum.Charge});
$('#ShippingOptions').html(radio);
```

Also, html **replaces** the content, are you sure you don't want to use `append` instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
var radio = '<input type="radio" name="ShippingMethod" value="'+datum.Charge+'"/>';
$('#ShippingOptions').html(radio);
```